# FFC (Flexible Flat Cable) ID please

Tags: connector

I am attempting to fix a DVD read write drive in a Sanyo VCR to DVD recorder.  I believe the problem to be mechanical, the current disk will not eject.  The disk can be played, as much as it can for a scratched disc.
I am unable to remove the DVD unit simply because I cannot unlock and release the ribbon connectors to the PCB on top of the unit so that I could remove the DVD unit from the appliance.
the connector from what I've just learned in the past 2 hours appears to be an FFC, CONNECTOR,  16POS (or 17POS), 1ROW, 0.??MM

[image: cable connector]

Comment: I don't see any sign of a latch mechanism. Maybe you just need to pull harder.

Answer (score 3):

This is an LIF(Low Insertion Force) FFC friction connector, and there is no latch.  The blue overlay on the end of the cable is there to stiffen the end of the cable so it doesn't bend when the cable is pushed into the connector.

LIF FFC connectors are also sometimes referred to as Non-ZIF FFC connectors.

A good linear pull on the blue overlay part of the cable should remove the cable from the connector, and it sometimes helps to slightly wiggle the cable side to side.  It should re-insert slightly easier than it was pulled out.

FFC connectors with a latch are referred to as ZIF(Zero Insertion Force) FFC connectors.

[The Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_flat_cable#Specifications) seems to imply that the blue stiffener is also useful for ZIF connectors, but I don't recall seeing this in practice.